# How to get a field from a queried document Flutter/Firetore

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I need to query a user's information but so far I am stuck on how I should get the values from fields in the document that keeps the information of the currently logged in user:

```
String firstName = "";
String lastName = "";

void getInfo() async{
  var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  var userQuery = Firestore.instance.collection('Users').where('e-mail', isEqualTo: '$user.email');

  // WHAT SHOULD I DO NEXT

}

@override
void initState(){
   super.initState();
   getInfo();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return new Scaffold(
    body: new Container(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text(firstName)
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text(lastName)
          )
        ]
      )
    )
  );
}
```

I have a collection named 'Users' where when a new user registers it creates a document to store his information. That document has fields of type String: 'e-mail', 'firstName', 'lastName'.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `documents` from that `collection` reference, after that you should have the data from the `document` , something like this :

```
   var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      var userQuery = Firestore.instance.collection('Users').where('e-mail', isEqualTo: user.email).limit(1);
      userQuery.getDocuments().then((data){ 
          if (data.documents.length > 0){
              setState(() {
                    firstName = data.documents[0].data['firstName'];
                    lastName = data.documents[0].data['lastName'];
                  });
          }
```

Comment: In your example you query users by email field. But `likedUsers` is a collection